# Rails - Controller :notice - Add a variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, scaffolding

I'm green behind the ears, but had a basic question about modifying the scaffolding's :notice to add a variable. For example, rails created the following create method for me:

```
 def create
    @order = Order.new(params[:order])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@order, :notice => 'Order was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @order, :status => :created, :location => @order }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @order.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

What I'm looking to do is add a variable to :notice so that it would print specifically what order was created (or edited with the update method). I tried some basic things using such as passing <%= order.id %>,though I felt this seemed unnatural within the controller?

Is adding a dynamic value possible within this format of this scaffolding? Or is it against the convention.

I appreciate the help, sorry if this is very newbish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beestings are the preferred way to insert dynamic values into strings in ruby. So if you wanted `@order.id` in your `:notice`, you could do this:

```
 def create
    @order = Order.new(params[:order])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@order, :notice => "Order id # #{@order.id} was successfully created.") }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @order, :status => :created, :location => @order }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @order.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: that should be a double quoted string :notice to have the string interpolation take place right?

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm using double quotes. I was trying to do this using the syntax for rendering in a view(obviously wrong), such as <%= %>. I really appreciate the help gentlemen. As I try to learn I do my best to figure this stuff out on my own but eventually crack. Never amazes me how fast you all are to respond. I sincerely thank both of you.

Comment: @Kombo Glad we could help you out. Have fun in your ruby and ror adventures!

Comment: @re5et You are correct. I looked over this detail in my initial post of my answer. This has been corrected. Thank you for catching that.